# No phD 2nd interview response

Tags: phd

I had appeared in PhD 2nd interview almost 16 days before. After interview professor told me to contact soon.I wrote 2 follow up emails but they did not answer. Even after ist interview i wrote them follow up emails and they did not reply and after 16 days of first interview they emailed me for 2nd interview. I am very anxious, what should I do now.